# Stop dismissing in an animated fashion for MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a [MPMoviePlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/). That ViewController always dismisses in an animated fashion. I want to dismiss it in 'NO animated' fashion. How can I do that?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];


[self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:NO completion:nil];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [moviePlayer.moviePlayer stop];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Currently, from what I have tried, all dismissings are in an animated fashion and I don't know why.

Comment: Is deprecated that function